# Is this a presentation of the other flag in the NAA review queue?

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

I was just reviewing the [Not An Answer Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?flagtype=answernotananswer) and I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783960/call-method-when-home-button-pressed-on-android/4784305#4784305) and flag description:

[image]

The answer has been flagged as *very low quality* and then it also has a flag that says:

> It's not an answer, or at least not to this question, however this was accepted instead of the real answer. – May 7 '12 at 5:53  × 4

Now I am in the review queue a lot and I don't recall ever seeing this before, is this an other flag that is being shown?  What is this unusual description that I am seeing?

Comment: That's an "Other" flag with a custom message. NAA would look more like the VLQ there.

Comment: Just curious - If someone fills "other" box and then changes to NAA, will the text be discarded for sure?

Comment: @Mołot - If they _submit_ the NAA? Yes. We only care about the text if they use `Other`.

Comment: @Oded I know that's what it is supposed to work, but as far as I recall this is about 3rd question in 2 weeks when it doesn't look like that. Just wanted to be sure there is no bug or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few months back, we did a massive refactoring of the flagging system. As part of this, the old code for classifying flags was ripped out and all old flags were migrated to the new system, analyzed and classified in the process.

...in a few cases, the migration got it wrong.

Internally, those are *both* NAA flags - but the old one wasn't supposed to be. As a result, you get to see what someone typed into the "other" box when flagging.

This should be strictly limited to a handful of posts with old flags, and (as always in the 10K flag queue) the flagger's name won't be shown.

Comment: That explains it, I was utterly confused why I was seeing what appeared to be an _other_ reason... For a second I had to check if I got a diamond next to my name. :)   Thanks for the details.